# query from elastic python client not returning all documents

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am querying data from elasticsearch via python.

This is the query,

```
es  =  Elasticsearch()
body= { "query" : { "match" : { "payment_mode" : 2 } } }
s = es.search(index='database-3',doc_type='booking', body=body)
```

This returns 10 records only,

```
print(len(s['hits']['hits']))
10
```

But there are around 30,000 records matching this query( I can verify it in kibana).

Am i missing some parameter ? WHy is it not returning all the records ?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719162/fetch-all-the-rows-using-elasticsearch-dsl/38719354#38719354

Comment: Try: "match_all"

Comment: By default it returns result of size 10. Use scan query type to get all results.